# Recipient claims cashier's check won't clear

Tags: united-states, cashier-check

I bought a car from a private seller in the US. To guarantee the availability of funds I issued a cashier's check to him. My banks account shows a withdrawal of the correct amount on the date that I issued the check. He claims that he deposited it two weeks ago and it still hasn't cleared. He claims that his bank reports the "limbo" status of the check as being because "the funds are not authorized for release". I called my bank to follow up on the status of the check but they claim they have no information about the check (whether it was deposited, cleared, or other).

Is there anything he or I can do to get more definitive status about the nature of the check?

Comment: Do you have possession of the car, along with a signed bill of sale and title? Or is the seller holding on to the title until the funds clear?

Comment: @spuck I have the car and legal possession of it.

Comment: @AdamO Then the transaction is done. You hold on to your proof of the cashier's cheque, and tell the person that the issue is between him, his bank, and your bank. **You** are no longer a responsible party for the transaction because the money has left your account already, and you have **zero control** over what happens after.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This sounds like a scam. Cashier's check is a check issued by the bank directly, and there's no reason for it not to clear. Unless he can show to you that *your* bank (that issued the check) refused to pay **and your bank confirms that**, you're in the clear.

TL;DR: Not your problem, disengage.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139571/discussion-on-answer-by-littleadv-recipient-claims-cashiers-check-wont-clear).